# Sort a named list in R

Tags: r, list, sorting, hashmap

I have a named list of term frequencies,

```
> list
$`in the`
[1] 67504

$`to the`
[1] 36666

$`of the`
[1] 79665

$`on the`
[1] 31261

$`to be`
[1] 25862

$`for the`
[1] 28332
```

I want to sort them into descending order according to the frequencies. How to do this? I tried **sort, sort.list, order** but had errors saying they don't accept this type of list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try by `unlist` and then use `order`

```
lst[order(unlist(lst),decreasing=TRUE)]
#  $`4`
#[1] 9

#$`3`
#[1] 7

#$`1`
#[1] 5

#$`2`
#[1] 4

#$`5`
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
lst <- setNames(list(5,4,7,9,2),1:5)
```

Answer (score 41):

If the list is large and involves large objects, would it be better to just use names?

```
 lst = lst[order(names(lst))]
```

Comment: The difference is your code orders by list element names, but the OP wants to order by list element values. That said, your code is what I was looking for.